# Automating SSH command

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

I am new to UFT.  I have a requirement where I have to automate ssh command.  I have used putty.   But script is sending junk characters to PUTTY.  I have used record and playback functionality if UFT

Comment: Please show the actual code you have used - very difficult to help you debug your code otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

Please use Window("name of the window").Activate or Window("name of the window").Highlight before inputing any data into the Putty by UFT.